# exhaustive list of all character patterns that HTML can't display as is or not display at all

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have a requirement in my web app to display a string received from the server as is. when I try to do that, a few character patterns like \u... or HTML entities are converted to their equivalent representations, extra whitespaces are lost, \n, \t etc are lost as well, some symbols are converted to their unicode representation.

I have written code/regular expressions to cater to the above cases, but I am not sure whether there can be more.

**EDIT:**
I have no control over the server.
Also I can't change the string once it is processed by the server, because the text contains some annotations which work based on the position and length

Example:

String recieved from server:

> "some random string, with extra  whitespaces, with \t and \n, and
>   some HTML entities like `&gt;` and unicode like \u2764"

it would be displayed in HTML like:

> "some random string, with extra whitespaces, with and , and some HTML
>   entities like > and unicode like ❤"

so if the annotations for the word HTML were earlier at position: 40 and length: 4, now the new string would have something else at position 40

NOTE: i cannot use textContent as i need to highlight the text based on these annotations and that would require some HTML.

An example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/44rct88n/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = "some random string, with  extra whitespaces, with \t and \n, and some HTML entities like &gt; and unicode like \u2764";
}
```

The output that i get is:

> Hello, some random string, with extra whitespaces, with and , and some
>   HTML entities like `&#62;` and unicode like ❤!

Comment: Sounds like you should properly encode the string, rather than attempt to regex HTML.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "character that HTML can't display".  You just need a better font.

Comment: @SLaks i didn't say it can't display, just meant it won't display as is , also not talking about characters but patterns

Comment: Then you just need to HTML-escape your text.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i don't have control over the server for sanitizing the string on the server side, the document encoding is UTF-8 on both sides

Comment: Then escape it client-side...

Comment: @SLaks i want to show them as is, because the server has some annotations attached to the document based on the offset and lengths

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i want the string as is because there are annotations attached to the document based on offset and length, and i need to highlight them in the UI, if some characters are not displayed as is it would mess up the highlighting

Comment: And if that string is injected malicious JavaScript?

Comment: @gaurav5430: Yes; that's exactly what escaping does.  If you want to display text, **you need to escape it**.

Comment: Create a proxy page that scrapes the html from the server side, and then escapes it properly.

Comment: @Slaks i am able to escape the above mentioned patterns, but i am just looking for inputs on whether there can be more of them which i have not yet found and would break the code in future

Comment: To display a JS string in HTML without having to escape anything, just assign it to the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property of a DOM element. Of course, you will need to get the data into a JS string to begin with, but that's a different question (and you haven't told us enough to answer that).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen i need to highlight some parts of the text, for which i am using span tags, that won't work with textContent

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara please see the edit

Comment: @SLaks please see the edit

Comment: There's still something going on in your code that you're not telling us about. HTML parsing will *not* turn `\t` or `\n` into whitespace; JavaScript string literal parsing will, but you haven't told us where or how or why that's happening.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact problem you are seeing with the unicode characters, and what your issue with whitespace is?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara if i recieve any unicode patterns in the string , they are converted to their unicode representations, which would change the text length and hence offsets for annotations

Comment: Why is this question tagging to AngularJS ? How does it relate?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara if there are 3 continous whitespaces in the server string, while displaying in HTML, they would be treated as a single whitespace

Comment: @ShaohaoLin because i am working on Angular for the front end, and it might happen that this particular issue may have a easier solution in angular

Comment: @IlmariKaronen forgive me, that is not an actual input/output from the web app, it was just an example from something i observed, i ll try to create a fiddle and post some code for better understanding

Comment: @IlmariKaronen i have added the fiddle, also \t won't be converted to whitespace but it would just be ignored

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara added a fiddle

Comment: @gaurav5430: It's not HTML but JavaScript string parsing that's replacing `\t` and `\n` with whitespace, or `\uNNNN` with Unicode. Try adding `console.log($scope.name);` to your fiddle, and check the developer console to see what your string actually contains.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen okay, some of these are because of js parsing, but some are due to HTML i guess, like the collapsed whitespaces, and ignoring whatever \t is replaced with in the js

Comment: just replace html special charecters and spaces with their equivalents.  enclose all in a <pre> tag.
`function ToDOM(str){
return str
 .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')          // must do &amp; first
 .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
 .replace(/'/g, '&#039;')
 .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
 .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
 .replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
 .replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')     // four? or more?
 .replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;')
;}`

Comment: @LuisSiquot i am doing something similar...bujt i don't want \t to appear as four spaces i want it to appear as \t and " as "

Comment: are you getting the text from the server with ajax?  with jquery?

Comment: @LuisSiquot using simple http request from angular

Comment: I didn't use angular. You face two issues here: 1- all **javascrip valid** escape sequences on the text are interpreted as that. That only can be done by javascript (instructed by angular).  Jquery has on ajax's call a `dataType` prameter that derermines the behavior of recovered data. if you can set this on angular you will need no conversion after getting the data. 2-Spaces (tabs, new lines, multiples) will need special care. replacements and/or the use of <pre>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96918/discussion-between-luis-siquot-and-gaurav5430).

Answer (score 1):

When you obtain the text from server, please use `text/plain` instead of `application/json`, the text remains "escaped" on RAW_TextFromServer and other data can be parsed with JSON.parse()

```
contentType : 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var theRawText = data.split(/(?:"theTextFromServer":\s*")((?:\\"|[^"])*)(?:")/)[1];
    var parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);
    parsedJson["RAW_TextFromServer"] = theRawText;
    return parsedJson;
}; 
}
```

I asume for the regex shown here, that your json has a key "theTextFromServer" that contains the text that you want to show.
Up to this point you are aware of javascript escaping, but you need html escaping to represent the text correctly.
This function is handy for that

```
function htmlEscape(str) { 
return   str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')       // must do &amp; first
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#039;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

To show spaces correctly you can use `<pre>` tag with apropiate styling.

Comment: Can you please tell me what happened when you tried this solution?